# Replacing a string which contains a slash sometimes

Tags: php, str-replace

I am doing a `str_replace()` on a string which sometimes contains a slash in it. This is the str_replace I have:

```
$text = str_replace('<Reference code="'.$ref['code'].'">','<a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent(\'openPage\',{\'code\':\''.$ref['code'].'\'})">',$text);
```

However, when the `$ref['code']` is (for example) `M100/3` it does not replace. So my question is, how do I make the replace happen?

Every value without a backslash works fine.

Also note, in some cases the str_replace is like this, so not only within a HTML parameter:

```
$text = str_replace('<Reference>'.(string)$ref.'</Reference>','<a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent(\'openPage\',{\'code\':\''.(string)$ref.'\'})">'.(string)$ref.'</a>',$text);
```

edit:

I tried addslashes() but it didn't seem to be working:

```
$text = str_replace('<Reference>'.addslashes((string)$ref).'</Reference>','<a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent(\'openPage\',{\'code\':\''.(string)$ref.'\'})">'.(string)$ref.'</a>',$text);
```

Comment: the problem was not the replace, but the detection it needed replacement in the first place. Solved it now. Without the addslashes it works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem seemed to be the detection of whether or not there should be a replace in the first place.

As the data is getting in via XML, the construction of that XML was wrong, and therefore was 1 layer too deep, and thus being unable to detect the text correctly, resulting in no URL replacements.

This being solved, fixed the problem. Also no need for an `addslahes()` there.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$ref['code']` with `addslashes($ref['code'])`.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. noticed I also got the question a bit wrong, it's a forward slash

Comment: wouldn't addslashes() also turn ' into \' and " into \"?

Comment: the problem was not the replace, but the detection it needed replacement in the first place. Solved it now. Without the addslashes it works too. Thanks anyway

Comment: @rodneyrehm: Yes, it would, but the OP mentioned the input string which was `M100/3` or sth similiar. No `'` or `"` there.

@Topener: It's nice you solved it. Add an answer and accept it - for the future visitors of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running those replacements for a number of codes, you might want to consider a regular expression instead:

```
<?php

$string = 'some <Reference>in_content</Reference> and <Reference code="attribute-with-content">bla</Reference> or even <Reference code="selfclosing" />';
$pattern = '#(<Reference>(?<a1>.*?)</Reference>)|(<Reference code="(?<a2>[^"]+)" />)|(<Reference code="(?<a3>[^"]+)">(.*?)</Reference>)#';

$_string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'replace_reference', $string);
function replace_reference($matches) {
    $key = $matches['a1'] ?: $matches['a2'] ?: $matches['a3'];
    // maybe do a lookup if $key is valid or something
    // if something is off, return $matches[0] to not replace anything
    return '<a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent(\'openPage\',{\'code\':\'' . $key . '\'})">';
}

var_dump($string, $_string);
```

With this, you wouldn't even have to know the codes you want to replace.